# How to find out the sum of the series $1^1+2^2 +\ldots+n^n?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Recently, I was exploring different ways to find out the sum of series but I've one in my mind to which I didn't have a sol. to. It goes :$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^i$$

Does anyone have a solution to this ?

Comment: There aren't any simpler forms.

Comment: @DipanjanDas, what is $x$ ?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001923 has few comments, and none about simpler forms.

Comment: There is a closed form for $\prod_{n=1}^x n^n$, but likely not the sum